# Unity hard real time synchronization

Tags: unity-game-engine, real-time, virtual-reality

I need to synchronize Unity app to a 3rd party app where time synchronization is crucial (1-2ms varient max).

The way this is done today (without Unity) is getting priority of the OS scheduler with a designated app which will assure a constant delay.

A constant delay is good enough as it can be used in the data analysis which is not done in real time. Today the constant delay is measured once on the beginning.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This kind of delays should be easy to achieve in a background thread.

Threads work well in Unity, despite common belief. The only thing you need to look out for is not to access Unity objects from the thread.

Easiest way to do this is to start a thread in a `MonoBehaviour.Start` with the [`IsBackground`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.isbackground(v=vs.110).aspx) property set to true (so you don't have to worry about it blocking your application exit) and communicate to and from it with a message queue (for example a `List<Action>` with `lock`ed access).